# Is UWP app compatible with 3D vision?

Tags: 3d, uwp, directx

I have a UWP app that provide user an ability to interact with a 3D model. I got a question from a customer, who is trying to use it with 3D Glasses and 3D software, whether is our app compatible with 3D Vision.

The app launches and he can interact with it, but it does not provide 'true' 3D mode.

Is there a way to make UWP app compatible with 3D Vision to provide users experience that they expect?

Comment: Do you mean 3d glasses like what NVidia sells, or VR headsets?

Comment: It is a 3d glasses like Nvidia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can render in stereoscopic 3D on UWP. For specific examples, game "Sonic Dash" works perfectly with 3D Vision on UWP.

Here's documentation on it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/stereoscopic-3d

If you use middleware to render your 3D object, it might even be simpler to enable. For instance in Unity, you just need to mark stereoscopic 3d as supported in the player settings:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StereoscopicRendering.html

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful!